# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug' in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, gradle

I am trying to use firebase and i followed the exact instructions to do so, but when i run my app i get this error:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my android\app\build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.both"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried clean and rebuild, but it did not work. I also tried multiDexEnabled true in the in build.gradle file (Module: app).

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

since flutter default min sdk version for android is 16 , you have to  add the following dependancies in your app level gradle file to enable multidex as mentioned in documentation 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16 
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' 
}
```

i tried the above solution and it's works for me

Comment: Thank you for your comment,  there was an issue in using compile i used implementation instead and there is the error:
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.last'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: did you place google-services.json file which u downloaded from firebase console  inside app directory if so , make sure your app id or package name match with app id u provided in firebase console , then go to tool > flutter > flutter clean , and build the app again

Comment: Yes i did so! and made sure that  applicationId is the same as the package name i wrote in the firebase console. It still does not work

Comment: IT FINALLY WORKED AFTER RESTARTING the visual code with all your suggestions included , thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `android/app/build.gradle` and add `multiDexEnabled true`.

```java
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```