# Can't resolve symbol android.support.v4.util.Pools in react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am working on react-native project.

After I update my modules by running 'npm install',

I cannot find class 'Pools' which located in 'android.support.v4.util' in 'react-native-gesture-handler'.

1. Why Is this error occur?
2. How can I fix this?

1.error (In case run "react-native run-android")
-cmd

```
Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
D:\weneepl\project_y-test2_t\project_y\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.util.Pools;
                              ^
  symbol:   class Pools
  location: package android.support.v4.util
D:\weneepl\project_y-test2_t\project_y\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
  private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool<RNGestureHandlerEvent> EVENTS_POOL =
                            ^
D:\weneepl\project_y-test2_t\project_y\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.util.Pools;
                              ^
  symbol:   class Pools
  location: package android.support.v4.util
D:\weneepl\project_y-test2_t\project_y\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:18: error: package Pools does not exist
  private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool<RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent> EVENTS_POOL =
                            ^
D:\weneepl\project_y-test2_t\project_y\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
          new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
                   ^
D:\weneepl\project_y-test2_t\project_y\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
          new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
                   ^
Note:D:\weneepl\project_y-test2_t\project_y\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors
```

2.React Native Environment Info:

```
System:
      OS: Windows 10
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz
      Memory: 7.59 GB / 15.96 GB
    Binaries:
      Yarn: 1.15.2 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
      npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.4.0.0 AI-183.5429.30.34.5452501
```

3.package.json

```
{
 "name": "project_y",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "start": "react-native run-android",
 "gradle-clean": "cd android & gradlew clean",
 "start-root": "react-native run-android --root",
 "test": "jest",
 "bundle": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file     
 index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/",
 "build": "cd android & gradlew assembleDebug"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.18.0",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "react": "16.6.3",
  "react-native": "0.58.5",
  "react-native-android-open-settings": "^1.3.0",
  "react-native-custom-checkbox": "^1.5.2",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.16",
  "react-native-grid-list": "^1.0.9",
  "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.1",
  "react-native-kakao-logins": "^1.3.6",
  "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
  "react-native-picker-select": "^6.0.0",
  "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.2",
  "react-native-super-grid": "^3.0.3",
  "react-native-svg": "^9.2.4",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.3.0",
  "react-native-webview": "^5.5.0",
  "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
  "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
  "redux": "^4.0.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
  "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
  "jest": "24.1.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
  "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0"
 },
 "jest": {
   "preset": "react-native"
 },
 "rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/",
    "resources/fonts"
  ]
 }
}
```

4.build.gradle(app/)

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.projecty.projecty"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.9"
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
 implementation 'com.igaworks.adbrix:abx-common-rm:+'

 implementation project(':react-native-webview')
 implementation project(':react-native-android-open-settings')
 implementation project(':react-native-kakao-logins')
 implementation project(':react-native-svg')
 implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
 implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
 implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')

 implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
 implementation "com.android.support:appcompat- 
 v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
 compile(name: 'IgawSSP_v2.0.6a', ext: 'aar')
 repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
 }
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
 from configurations.compile
 into 'libs'
}

subprojects {
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 
 'http://devrepo.kakao.com:8088/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
 }
}
```

5.build.gradle(android/)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/igaworks/AdbrixRmSDK'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://devrepo.kakao.com:8088/nexus/content/groups/public/'
        }


    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

I expect the complete of build project.

Answer (score 26):

I was having this same issue with React Native 0.60.0 and none of above answers gave me a solution, so i fixed with this:

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```

jetifier is an AndroidX transition tool in npm format, with a react-native compatible style.

> If you use React Native modules with native Java code that isn't
>   converted to AndroidX, and your app is AndroidX, you probably need
>   this

so, in RN 0.60 you need AndroidX

Comment: I was having this issue with 0.60 after installing react-navigation (and all of it's dependencies). This solution fixed my problem.

Comment: Work for me too. RN0.60

Comment: Not works for me now is throwing: `package androidx.core.util does not exist`

Answer (score 20):

- Open project use AndroidStudio3.3+

[image: AS project]

- Click module android[react-native-gesture-handler]
- Click top Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX
- Done

Comment: Thanks great answer!

Comment: This may be useful for a single package, but isn't helpful for projects that need to be built in a CI environment with many dependencies.

Comment: o that's great        this should be the correct answer of this problem.  @playSCforever well don

Comment: What about if you have the problem with circlec?i, I cannot apply this solution.

Comment: What about us that don't want to migrate over androidx

Answer (score 7):

Opened the project in android studio -> browse to the specified file in RNGestureHandler

remove this

```
import android.support.v4.util.Pools;
```

And add this

```
import androidx.core.util.Pools;
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar thing happened to me. I checked android documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/Pools

- Go to **android/build.gradle**

  - In section **dependencies** add
    `classpath "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1"`

This is my first time writing answer on stack overflow, I hope it is in good answer format.

Comment: Great for first answer! I just added some formatting for better readability

Answer (score 2):

Please remove these two lines from `gradle.properties`

`android.useAndroidX=true`

`android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: This solution works. I added it and I fixed to import from androidx. thank you

Comment: This Solution Worked after adding multidex true in app/ build.gradle.

Multidex Add Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264534/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithexternallibsdexmergerford

Answer (score 2):

> Nothing was working for me but this worked.

Make the `enableJetifier=false` in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false
```

Comment: I also set `android.useAndroidX` to `false` and it works for me

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. Just make sure that you've updated the version of `react-native-gesture-handler`. If you do so then it should work. for me it worked this way.

Answer (score 1):

Make changes in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
npm install --save-dev jetifier
```

or

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetify
npx react-native run-android
```

Call `npx jetify` run in the postinstall target of your package.json (Any time your dependencies update you have to jetify again)

Answer (score 1):

To make that working just edit **`android>gradle.properties`** file by adding these two lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```